# ClientConfig.setHeavyweight - Volt Network 1 & Volt Reaper Thread

Tags: voltdb

In [ClientConfig Javaoc](https://docs.voltdb.com/javadoc/java...eight-boolean-)
says that the client will use Runtime.coresAvailable / 2 (let's say N = cores / 2), that means that must be N **Volt Network Threads** and N **Volt Reaper Threads** ? Or N/2 **"Volt Network Threads** and N/2 **Volt Reaper Threads** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at VoltDB. There is a discrepancy in the Javadoc, the formula is actually max(1, (cores/4)) for the number of Volt Network threads. The thread names will be "Volt Client Network - 1" and subsequent numbers. Each client will have a single "VoltDB Client Reaper Thread".